# What Regular Expression do I need to match "3213.32.2311" and similar?

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to match input like:

```
3213.32.2311
```

Format required is:

- Four numeric characters
- a `.`
- 2 numeric characters
- a `.`
- 4 numeric characters.

Comment: Getting other people to write code snippets for you is about the worst possible way to learn anything about coding. If you don't understand something, questions like 'Why does this regexp mean this' will actually help you learn.

Comment: Is there a question the OP has asked that isn't "gimme the codez", closed or a dup?

Answer (score 4):

Get yourself a regex cheatsheet such as http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Though they look daunting, they're really not that bad. I can never remember the syntax - so a good cheat sheet is a must.

Comment: Also, reading a guide/cheatsheet and writing the expression yourself will help you learn the syntax much quicker than a copy-paste answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$
```

Comment: @Peter - sorry, force of habit. I virtually never write a regex where I don't care about what the different parts are.

Comment: Perhaps you should use regex more then. ;) I frequently have quick jobs that don't need captures. But no problem, it's just a little thing that bugs me (though not quite as much as `^(this)$` when `$0` or `\0` is already available). Could be useful to mention both ways in your answer, in case it helps with what the OP is doing. :)

Answer (score 1):

`\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}`

Comment: Annoyingly enough I did, but StackOverflow editing escaped it. Had to do \\.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}`